# How to display list<> in gridview ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have DAL code in asp.net c# for select all user of my table_users in DB sql server.

my DAL :

```
public class Users
{
    private string _UserName;

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _UserName; }
        set { _UserName = value; }
    }
    private string _Pass;

    public string Pass
    {
        get { return _Pass; }
        set { _Pass = value; }
    }
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
    private string _Family;

    public string Family
    {
        get { return _Family; }
        set { _Family = value; }
    }

    private string _Mobile;

    public string Mobile
    {
        get { return _Mobile; }
        set { _Mobile = value; }
    }
}

public List<Users> GetAllUsers()
{
    List<Users> usersList = null;

    using (DataTable table = SqlDBHelper.ExecuteSelectCommand("GetAllUsers", CommandType.StoredProcedure))
    {
        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            usersList = new List<Users>();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                Users user = new Users();

                user.UserName = table.Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();
                user.Pass = table.Rows[0]["Pass"].ToString();
                user.Name = table.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
                user.Family = table.Rows[0]["Family"].ToString();
                user.Mobile = table.Rows[0]["Mobile"].ToString();

                usersList.Add(user);
            }
        }
    }

    return usersList;
}
```

and my BLL code for call:

```
public List<Users> GetAllUsers()
{
    return userDB.GetAllUsers();
}
```

and now I want to call method for display data in grid view .

```
public List<Users> usersList = null;
UsersHadler userDB = new UsersHadler();
usersList = userDB.GetAllUsers();

foreach (Users user1 in usersList)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = usersList;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I have 3 user in data base.uer1 and user2 and user3
**the problem is that I see in gridview 3 row for one user1.**
user1
user1
user1
what is wrong.?
thanks for reply

`

Comment: You really need to understand loops better. Look what you're looping over in your DAL. You're looping the rows in the table,  but then on each iteration you're going back to the table, to the 0th row. You should reference the row that's declared in your loop. It's very similar to the issue Jaquez pointed out to you in binding the usersList repeatedly to the GridView.

Comment: Security Alert! Are you storing plaintext passwords in the database? That's a big security violation! Passwords should be one-way hashed and salted. Additionally, your `Users` class should just be called `User` represents a single user, not a collection. And you should look into [auto properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties) which can cut down on the unnecessary code.

Comment: hi thanks. for reply .  especially for your Security Alert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `foreach` loop.  You are going through `usersList` once for each user and binding the entire list to `GridView1`.  You only need to do it once.

```
public List<Users> usersList = null;
UsersHadler userDB = new UsersHadler();
usersList = userDB.GetAllUsers();
GridView1.DataSource = usersList;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

You also probably want to call the `GetAllUsers` method from your BLL instead of calling the one from the DAL directly in your view.  Otherwise, what was the point of the BLL?

Your problem is in the DAL version of `GetAllUsers`.  You are referring only to `Rows[0]` in the `foreach` loop.

```
user.UserName = table.Rows[0]["UserName"].ToString();
user.Pass = table.Rows[0]["Pass"].ToString();
user.Name = table.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
user.Family = table.Rows[0]["Family"].ToString();
user.Mobile = table.Rows[0]["Mobile"].ToString();
```

Replace the `foreach` loop in the DAL copy of `GetAllUsers` with this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    Users user = new Users();

    user.UserName = row["UserName"].ToString();
    user.Pass = row["Pass"].ToString();
    user.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
    user.Family = row["Family"].ToString();
    user.Mobile = row["Mobile"].ToString();

    usersList.Add(user);
}
```

Comment: Are you still getting the same result?

Comment: @mason you stole the words right off of my keyboard.

Comment: Well, technically you did that to me. I had my answer all typed up but you got it there faster.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: sorry. I cant speak english well.